# How to extract the attributes of a function of an instance passed as a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I extract the attributes of the "SimpleSubscriber object from the following method object?

```
<bound method SimpleSubscriber.process of <__main__.SimpleSubscriber object at 0x2ede150>>
```

This object has been passed as a function, but is a function of an instance as we can see above. I would like to reference the above object (saved in a list in different class than its own) from the instance where this function resides.

Nothing in `dir()` seems to help.

`self` within the instance returns:

```
<__main__.SimpleSubscriber object at 0x2ede150>
```

so this instance cannot reference itself in its own method, from within the other class.

So basically, I am trying to access the attributes of

```
<__main__.SimpleSubscriber object at 0x2ede150>
```

from

```
<bound method SimpleSubscriber.process of <__main__.SimpleSubscriber object at 0x2ede150>>
```

I'm trying to extract unique identifiers of the instance. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bound method holds references to the original function and the instance it is bound to; this is how it passes in the instance as the first argument when your method is called.

If you wanted to access the instance it is bound to, use the `__self__` attribute:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> bound_bar = Foo().bar
>>> bound_bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x101e5f6d8>>
>>> bound_bar.__self__
<__main__.Foo object at 0x101e5f6d8>
```

You can then access any attributes you need on that instance, including the method itself again:

```
>>> bound_bar.__self__.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x101e5f6d8>>
```

Attributes like these are documented in the [Datamodel reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), but for a quick overview the [`inspect` module has a handy table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members).

Comment: Thank you Martijn. I was worried the question would be difficult to understand, but you understood and gave me exactly the solution I have been looking for! Thank you. \_\_self\_\_ is not in the dir for the function. Do you know why? Is it something obvious I have overlooked?

Comment: @hellome: `dir()` is not an *exhaustive* list; as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) puts it: *it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information*, and *it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names*.

Comment: @hellome: that said, `__self__` **is** listed as an attribute of the method object, at least on Python 3.4. `'__self__' in dir(bound_bar)` is True.

Comment: Ok, not so sure about 3.4 cuz i'm on 3.2, but in my case, the equivalent of your 'bound_bar' was sent to another class to preform. Calling dir() on it from within that other class did not return a \_\_self\_\_. But your first, comment response answers that. Thanks again.